# Declare Multiple Java Arrays on Same Line?

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to initialize and/or declare multiple arrays in the same line in Java?

ie.

```
int a, b, c, d, e = 4
```

works but

```
int[] a, b, c, d, e, = new int[4]
```

doesn't seem to work (size of array is 4)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Bear in mind that

```
int a, b, c, d, e = 4;
```

is declaring 5 ints but only initialising 'e'.

In the same way,

```
int[] a, b, c, d, e = new int[4];
```

will only initialise e.

You'd need something like

```
int[] a=new int[4], b=new int[4], etc...
```

which frankly, isn't worth one-lining...

Answer (score 5):

try

`int[] a = new int[4], b = new int[4], c = new int[4], d = new int[4], e = new int[4];`

You have to instantiate an array for each variable if you want to create five different arrays.

If you want to create one array and reference it from five variables Goran has the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `new` keyword
Try this:

```
int[] a, b, c, d, e = new int[4];
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to put that in my question (edited), but it still won't compile in BlueJ (variable a may not have been initialized).

Comment: Interesting. It seems that the array object had been assigned only to reference named `e`.

Comment: It should be `int[] a, b, c, d, e ; a = (b = (c = (d = (e = new int[4]))));` The assignment operators' return value is the assigned value. However, as Jon already said, they would all still refer to the same array.. And it's two lines now.. and ugly..

Answer (score 2):

<strike>What you tried is possible only for value types. In Java arrays are reference types i.e. objects.</strike>

What you tried is not possible (as Gwyn explained).

On the other hand you could:

```
int[][] arrays = new int[4][5];
```

And then use: `arrays[0]`, `arrays[1]`.. instead od `a`,`b`.