# Initializing large number of arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, nullpointerexception, initialization

I am writing an program for an engineering application that needs a large number of 1x3 arrays to store coefficients for a very long rigid body mechanics equation. As such, I have about 90 arrays that need to conform to a very specific and longstanding engineering syntax. Imagine I have the following:

```
double[] a = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
double[] b = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
double[] c = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
etc.......
double[] zz = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
```

You can see that this is quite unwieldy.

As I understand from reading [this discussion on primitive declaration in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328339/declare-multiple-java-arrays-on-same-line), there is no way to initialize a list of variables to the same value. For instance, in the following code:

```
double[] a, b, c, ...... zy, zz = new double[3];
```

However, this only initializes array `zz`, is there really no better way to initialize a large number of arrays than with the first method in this post? Is there a better overall approach to storing a large number of arrays that need to be descriptively named? I would like to be able to store the data in a two dimensional array but unfortunately these values need to be descriptive.

For reference, I need to initialize these arrays because the data that is being assigned to them originates from a list that is passed to the object instance when it is constructed. I can't assign a value to an uninitialized variable or I get a `NullPointerException`. For example:

```
a[index] = listWithDataIWantToAssign.get(listIndex);
```

returns a `NullPointerException` when using the second (invalid) method of initialization mentioned above.

Comment: you can try `ArrayList` just asking

Comment: This approach has the very strong smell of one class taking on more responsibility than it realistically should.  Can each array be independent of another?  That is, can you declare `c` independent from `d` and have them live in separate places?

Comment: What about a class with an array member?

Comment: @asteriskNinja I would like to use an arraylist for simplicity but I need to be able to be able to refer to each field by name. At some point these values will be introduced into a very long equation and it isn't really helpful for the engineers maintaining and working with that math to only see values as some index of an ArrayList as opposed to the longstanding nomenclature of the coefficients used in this area of expertise.

Comment: @AmiHollander can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: @Makoto I've already tried paring down this class as much as possible but to the best of my knowledge there isn't really any way to further isolate these values. Unfortunately the equations I'm dealing with are in the field of Hydromechanics and are quite complex.

Comment: Let me rephrase:  is there a way you could create an object that contained a single array and instead newed that up however many times you needed it?  Writing Java in this imperative method isn't exactly conducive although it *can* be done.

Comment: @Makoto, I guess I could take that approach, but then I just end up with an obnoxious number of objects instead of an obnoxious number of arrays. I'm really hoping for some approach to initializing values in one shot so that I can add and take away terms easily in the future without losing track of the values I need to perform these calculations.

Comment: This is why I claimed it to be a strong smell.  Personally I'm thinking along the lines of a wrapper class for your array but without knowing/understanding how these arrays interact, it's tough to say.  You're basically describing [a symptom of a problem, but not what the problem really is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/175248), so it's kinda tricky to get narrow-scope help for this.  There probably isn't a better way than to declare a whole heap o' arrays for your current scenario, but if we could figure out how those arrays relate, we could write a clearer solution to it.

Comment: why you don't use a matrix with 3 (columns) x n (rows) ?

Comment: @KevinWallis , When I actually write out the equations in a method, I would like to be able to use the actual mathematical terms as opposed to array indices, for instance, `cos(reynoldsNumber[i])` is easier to understand that `cos(coefficientArray[2][7])`. Readability is extremely important for this application.

Comment: Only a idea: it would also be possible to add functions which add the ability to call the method this way e.g. `cos(reynoldsNumber(i))`.
But i also like the approach of a wrapper object when the performance is not so important.

Comment: Learn about collections. They will help a lot. Try experimenting with `ArrayList` for a start!

Comment: @jay, Thanks for the contribution, but I am quite aware of the ArrayList class and its implementation. My main concern is that List values are not uniquely identifiable other than their index , which greatly hampers readability for lengthy equations with established nomenclature. Like I stated above: cos(reynoldsNumber[1]) is easier to understand that cos(coefficientArray.get(1)).

Comment: IK arrays are good but i agree with @Jay as you have other options like `linked list` and readability depends on how you write the code not on what data stricture you use. and collections have high amount of readability with some advanced methods PS i don't even know about all methods of arrays

Comment: FYI `arraylist` is advance implementation of `array` (till my knowledge)

Comment: @Makoto, there are a series of equations that define the motion of a rigid body, where there are manycoefficients with 3 degrees of freedom, that is, they have x, y, and z components. (and k, m, and n components for axial forces). I need to be able to clearly implement a replica of these equations in Java based on a given list of coefficient values determined by testing. There are 6 equations in total, one for each degree of freedom of the model. Each of these equations has approximately 20 to 30 coefficients that need to be represented in a standard nomenclature used in Hydromechanics.

Comment: @XeroG `ArrayList` is some kind of advanced implementation of `Array`. You may try `LinkedList` or maybe use `HashMap<String, ArrayList>` where `String` could be used to uniquely identify your array, so that you don't actually have to declare 99 of those variables. Just initialize them when you need it... As far as I understood your concern. Using this kind of approach can reduce your code by a drastic percent. And then you can write a method which returns the value from the required array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to work with a large ammount of arrays it's preferable to use a double array instead of excessive ammount of variables. I recommand you to create a simple double array `double[][] myArray = new double[90][3]`

> Is there a better overall approach to storing a large number of arrays that need to be descriptively named?

if all variables are named it will be difficult to not type all names. But instead of name variables why not name values it by ints using static names ?

you can create a class keeping all names like that :

```
public static class VariablesNames{
    private static int counter = 0;

    public static final int NAME_1 = counter++;
    public static final int NAME_2 = counter++;
    public static final int NAME_3 = counter++;
    ...
}
```

Then use these variables in your code

```
double val = myArray[VariablesNames.NAME_1][0];
```

> is there really no better way to initialize a large number of arrays than with the first method in this post?

If you have a really large ammout of arrays, it's not really usefull to initialise all arrays at the beginning. You can lazy load the array and use getter an setter on it

```
double[][] myArray = new double[90][];

public void init(int position){
    if(myArray[position] == null){
        myArray[position] = new double[3];
    }
}

public double[] get(int position) {
    init(position);
    return myArray[position];
}


public void set(int position, List<Double> listWithDataIWantToAssign){
    init(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        myArray[position][i] = listWithDataIWantToAssign.get(i);
    }
}
```

Then use these methods in your code

```
set(VariablesNames.NAME_2, listWithDataIWantToAssign);
double val = get(VariablesNames.NAME_2)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return a 2d array of 'double' primitives, with size [N][3]. N is the number of arrays, or *90* in your example, and 3 the three double numbers in each array:

```
public static double[][] initDoubleArrays (int N) {     
    double[][] doublesArray = new double[N][3];     
    // the doubles will be set to 0.0 by default.
    return doublesArray;
}
```

Alternatively, the following code will return a list where each element is a Double[] array with three Double objects

```
public static List<Double[]> initArrays (int nArrays) {
    List<Double[]> arrays = new ArrayList<Double[]>(nArrays);
    for (int i = 0; i<nArrays; i++) {
        Double[] doubles =  { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
        arrays.add(doubles);
    }               
    return arrays;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a List couldn't be the best approach you should consider creating your own Factory, improved a little by maybe playing with the size, and the initial value...

like:

```
public class MyClass implements IArrayFactory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass foo = new MyClass();
    List<List<Double>> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        l.add(foo.getListDouble(3, 0.0));
    }
    System.out.println(l);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Double> getListDouble(int size, double initVal) {
    Double[] d = new Double[size];
    Arrays.fill(d, initVal);
    return Arrays.asList(d);
    }
}

interface IArrayFactory {
    List<Double> getListDouble(int size, double initVal);
}
```

Comment: `List<double[]>` - not the best approach to this if those arrays are meant to be interacted with in some sane fashion...

Comment: Thanks for the double list factory, but since I can only represent the value of an ArrayList<Double> by its index I lose out on a lot readability, especially given that a lot of the complexity of this program comes from the equations governing its behavior. What 'm really hoping to find out is if there is a way I can flexibly initialize a large number of variables in Java, not contained in a collection.