# Why can't I initialize several arrays at once?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to fill the arrays with random numbers, but the IDE refuses to work even with a single array. Something is wrong with arrays initialization. According to Schildt's Java SE 8 guide, it's possible to create a couple of arrays like I did, but if I try to do something with any of them, I get an error shown below.

If I initialize just 1 array, I get no errors. But, if I need many arrays to work with, how should I initialize them? One by one? I haven't faced such a thing in C++.

I know it's better to create a 2D array, but I have an exercise to work with  some 1D arrays now.

P.S: if you don't mind, an extra question. Is it possible to index those arrays to operate them inside loops later. Maybe with the help of enums or what?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = new int[4];
    //int a[],b[],c[],d[],e[],f[],g[],h[],i[] = new int[4]; - this doesn't work either
    Random random = new Random();

        for (int y=0; y<4; y++) {
            a[y] = random.nextInt(9); //The local variable a may not have been initialized
            System.out.print(a[y] + " "); //The local variable a may not have been initialized
        }   
}
```

Comment: Didn't you get a compile error at the very 2nd line in the main method?

Comment: I think this might have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328339/declare-multiple-java-arrays-on-same-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write something like

```
int a, b = 5;
```

only b will be initialized.

What you can do however is

```
int a, b;
a = b = 5;
```

And both will be initialited with the same value. Now when you'd do the same with arrays, so

```
int[] a, b;
a = b = new int[4];
```

they'd actually point to the same instance/reference, which does not make any sense, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have a fixed number of "length 4 int arrays" you can create a 2D array instead of multiple 1D arrays of length 4.
This would look something like this:

```
int[][] a = new int[9][4] 
//here 9 is the number of arrays you tried to create above, and 4 is the initial length
```